# How can I create a column which groups all the dates and their data in two columns? (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I have information about wind turbines with different columns that give us features about them. The problem is that the last 20 columns of the dataframe are dates in which we have the capacity of a wind turbine for that date.

I would like to create two aditional columns: a date column in which I have all the dates when the capacity is measured and another column with the corresponding capacity for that date.

Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

```
Id <- c(1, 2, 3)
measure_1 <- c ("A", "B", "C")
measure_2 <- c (10, 20, 30)
date_1 <- c(1, 0, 1)
date_2 <- c(1, 2, 4)
date_3 <- c(1, 8, 9)

df <- data.frame(Id, measure_1, measure_2, date_1, date_2, date_3)
```

| Id | measure_1 | measure_2 | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 20 | 0 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | C | 30 | 1 | 4 | 9 |

And the result I would like to get is:

| Id | measure_1 | measure_2 | date | capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | date_1 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 10 | date_2 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 10 | date_3 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 20 | date_1 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 20 | date_2 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 20 | date_3 | 8 |
| 3 | C | 30 | date_1 | 1 |
| 3 | C | 30 | date_2 | 4 |
| 3 | C | 30 | date_3 | 9 |

Maybe the solution is more easy than I think it is but I have tried to approach the problem in different ways and I can't find the correct one.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reshape2

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df,c("Id","measure_1","measure_2"))

  Id measure_1 measure_2 variable value
1  1         A        10   date_1     1
2  2         B        20   date_1     0
3  3         C        30   date_1     1
4  1         A        10   date_2     1
5  2         B        20   date_2     2
6  3         C        30   date_2     4
7  1         A        10   date_3     1
8  2         B        20   date_3     8
9  3         C        30   date_3     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr()` to preserve the order of "date" and rename the columns:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -c(Id, measure_1, measure_2), names_to = "date", values_to = "capacity")

     Id measure_1 measure_2 date capacity
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 A                10 date_1     1
2     1 A                10 date_2     1
3     1 A                10 date_3     1
4     2 B                20 date_1     0
5     2 B                20 date_2     2
6     2 B                20 date_3     8
7     3 C                30 date_1     1
8     3 C                30 date_2     4
9     3 C                30 date_3     9
```